# Excel Delete empty row in a looped range

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple identical arrays that based on the number that the user selects i display these number of arrays. Every array is divided into three arrays.

so if the user select 3 i show consecutive identical arrays.

I want to delete the empty rows inside every array.

What we can do is loop on every array as follows:

```
For i = 1 To NbTasks


        For j = (39 + (i - 1) * 50) To (44 + (i - 1) * 50)
        If IsEmpty(Cells(j, "D").Value) Then ActiveSheet.rows(j).Delete
        End If
        Next j

        D = 50 + (i - 1) * 50
        If IsEmpty(Cells(D, "B").Value) Then ActiveSheet.rows(D).Delete
         End If

        For Z = (56 + (i - 1) * 50) To (64 + (i - 1) * 50)
        If IsEmpty(Cells(Z, "B").Value) Then ActiveSheet.rows(Z).Delete

        End If
        Next Z Next i
```

But the problem is whenever the condition is true, the row is deleted so the index will become out of bound and delete rows outside the range specified.

Comment: General rule when deleting is to work *backwards*, i.e. `For i=Max_Row to Min_Row Step -1`

Comment: row deletion is done in a backwards loop with a - step. Or all in one go with a union of ranges.

Comment: Deleting the rows in a loop is a bad idea... [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657070/want-to-delete-all-n-a-from-the-multiple-sheet-in-one-go) is one example on how to it efficiently :)

Comment: Thank you for your comments.