# Copy paste operation resulting in #VALUE! Error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to combine three sheets into one master sheet, it's working fine however my two sheets contain formula and if pasted directly it gives me `#VALUE!`  which is obviously because of formula containing columns.

So what I want is to paste special all three sheets into one master sheet so that it will not give me `#VALUE!` in the master sheet.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub Combine3Sheet()

    Dim Ary As Variant
    Dim Ws As Worksheet

    Ary = Array("Sheet1", “Sheet2", "Sheet3")
    Sheets("Master").Name = "Master"

    For Each Ws In Worksheets(Ary)
        Ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy Sheets("Master") _
        .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Call Formatting

    Next Ws

End Sub
```

Comment: There's no point calling `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` back-to-back. Did you mean for the previous line to occur in between these two?

Comment: My question was to paste special the data instead of copy and paste.. currently its combining three sheet into one coping and pasting which takes the formula with it as well which give an error cell

Comment: Ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy Sheets("Master").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)————— Can we change it to paste special

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PasteSpecial xlPasteValues` instead of `Copy Destination:=`

```
ws.UsedRange.Offset(1).Copy
Sheets("Master").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: @Rajeshji no problem, mark the answer as correct then please (check mark sign - ✓ ) so the question stays no longer open. Also as I checked you did not accept correct answer to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39657070/want-to-delete-all-n-a-from-the-multiple-sheet-in-one-go) either

Comment: Sir.. I have checked on correct sign on both the answer... Thank You!